# How to get organization tree google workspaces

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

i am looking at building a website meant to be used by companies that are using google workspaces.

How can I get the companies organization tree when they are being onboarded?

I found this API but i don't think it returns the correct information https://developers.google.com/workspace/explore?filter=&discoveryUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fpeople.googleapis.com%2F%24discovery%2Frest%3Fversion%3Dv1&discoveryRef=resources.people.methods.listDirectoryPeople&operationId=people.people.listDirectoryPeople

Ideally i want the Full company tree, including who is managing who, etc.

Thanks

Looked through the google workplaces api https://developers.google.com/workspace/explore?filter=&discoveryUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fpeople.googleapis.com%2F%24discovery%2Frest%3Fversion%3Dv1&discoveryRef=resources.people.methods.listDirectoryPeople&operationId=people.people.listDirectoryPeople